# Eliminar todos los datos de una tabla y dejar solo los datos del ultimo mes

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysqldb

Hola tengo una tabla que se llama LogNotificacion en un motor de base de datos mysql, estoy tratando de borrar todos los datos y solo dejar los del ultimo mes pero no he podido dar con la sentencia sql de pronto alguien me puede ayudar como realizarla?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la sentencia que realizaste y no funciona?

Comment: ¿Cómo es la definición de la tabla?

Comment: Podrías mostrarnos lo que has intentado por favor (aunque no funcione)? Nosotros necesitamos señales de que eres parte del esfuerzo por responder a tu propia pregunta para que sepamos que no le hacemos la tarea a alguien. Además, así tu pregunta será mejor recibida! Por cierto, un par de personas pidieron más información, podrías agregarla en la pregunta por favor?

Answer (score 2):

supongo que tienes una columna que almacena la fecha de carga del registro, si es así es super simple.

```
delete from tabla_a_borrar
where fecha_registro <= to_date('01-02-2022','DD-MM-YYYY');
```